# Publish a WinForm program that uses Word 2013

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I've created a winform program that uses .dll of Word 2013 (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace). But, I want to publish the app to work with other Word versions (2010, 2007). So, What should I do? I should add .dlls of other Word versions and when the program is loading, detect which version of Office is installed? ...

Thank you,
Mohsen

Comment: Have you tried it with other word versions? Does it work only with the word 2013 dll?

Comment: No. It cited in MSDN, that you should install an Office.  I have 2013, but with other version ...!?

Comment: Well, first thing to do is to check which behavior you're having with other versions. If you're absolutely sure it won't work with other versions, then you'll have to adapt your code so that it works with every version of dll you want to support. Anyway I think you should check first